# Perl XML::LibXML where did I go wrong

Tags: xml, perl

I'm having a rather stupid moment here. The problem is that it has been a two day stupid moment, and not knowing anyone who knows perl, I'm getting rather messed up here.
Consider the following code:

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use XML::LibXML;
  my $filename = 'f:\proxml\1561\15610024.xml';
    my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
  my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($filename);

  for my $line ($doc->findnodes('Document/Page/Lines')) {
          for my $property ($line->findnodes('/Document/Page/Lines/OCRCharacters')) {
    print $property->textContent();
  }
  }
```

I'm trying to print the OCRCharacters contents.
Here's the bare bones of the xml file:

```
<Document>
  <Page>
    <Lines>
      <NumberOfLines>21</NumberOfLines>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <OCRCharacters>Test ocr in XML</OCRCharacters>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <OCRCharacters>This is the 2nd line</OCRCharacters>
    </Lines>
  </Page>
</Document>
```

I have searched here for answers to my problem, but I'm obviously missing something pretty fundamental.
If you have a solution, and the time, please come back.
Many thanks

Comment: And just what *is* your problem?  You haven't said.

Answer (score 0):

```
$line->findnodes('/Document/Page/Lines/OCRCharacters')
```

should be

```
$line->findnodes('OCRCharacters')
```

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_fh(\*DATA);

for my $line ($doc->findnodes('/Document/Page/Lines')) {
   for my $property ($line->findnodes('OCRCharacters')) {
      print $property->textContent(), "\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
<Document>
  <Page>
    <Lines>
      <NumberOfLines>21</NumberOfLines>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <OCRCharacters>Test ocr in XML</OCRCharacters>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <OCRCharacters>This is the 2nd line</OCRCharacters>
    </Lines>
  </Page>
</Document>
```

Output:

```
Test ocr in XML
This is the 2nd line
```

Comment: Ikagami, My problem was that the program ran, but produced no output at all. Apologies for my vague explanation, but your solution has worked.

Comment: Hi again, no, I jumped the gun! the code still doesn't work for me.